# Indexing a CouchDB view with ElasticSearch

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

Using the [CouchDB river](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/382), it is possible to index CouchDB databases.
Is it also possible to index a CouchDB view with Elastic Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. See https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb/pull/2

BTW you can checkout my pull request, build it and start to query views...